# Incrementing a Value in a Structs without a Pointer?

Tags: c++

I need to increment an integer value in a struct without using a pointer.  Is this possible?  I know the following will NOT increment the value, but I don't know where to go from here?  I'm using C++ and this is a 100 level class.

```
list[wordIndex].holdCount++;
```

`list` is my struct
`wordIndex` is the value of the place the integer is stored in the for loop.
`holdCount` is the element holding the integer value that I want to increment.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What makes you believe the following will NOT increment a value? Given appropriate definitions for various names, it most certainly would.

Comment: _"I know the following will NOT increment the value."_ Why's that?

Comment: This cannot possibly be answered without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which would, among other things, show the definition of `list`, `wordIndex`, `holdCount`, and of their types. It depends on the return type of `operator []`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

That code will increment the integer just fine.

Did you not try it?

Comment: So..... if it is appropriate, then I am failing somewhere else!!! At least I won't spin my wheels on this.  Thank you!

Comment: Next time please _test_ your assertion before making us spin our wheels on it!!